# Android Web Application - application is displaying above keyboard

Tags: android, web

I am running my web application built in using HTML5 on the android browser.
I have one search box on my home screen.
Whenever I tap inside the search input box the virtual keyboard appears and the application is shrinks and resizing with whatever available place above the keyboard.
This behavior I have seen on samsung galaxy tab (3.1), samsung galaxy note (2.3.6) and samsung S3(4.0)

But, if I run the same web application on the HTC desire(2.3.5) or even HTC evo 3D, the keyboard appears above the app and the application does not shrinks.

I am looking if there are any setting for web browser on android.

I know there are manifest file settings like resize pan and other for android hybrid as well as native application but I want to know if there are any settings for normal web application running on android browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in your manifest file.

*You might need to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan".*

Place this code in the activity under application , where u want such setting

Comment: as i mentioned it is plane web application which is running on android browser. I am not running a hybrid/native application.